# How do I ask for permission to send notifications on windows 11 using python

Tags: python, windows, notifications, exe, inno-setup

I'm using the win11toast library and everything works until I use auto-py-to-exe to convert it into an exe file.

I know the code is running and when I go to the notification center on windows it doesn't show.

- I've tried stuff like running it as admin and trying to look in the properties of the exe file.
- I know changing the setting is Auto-py-to-exe won't work.
- I've also tried to use Inno setup compiler to make it an app but I still didn't figure out how to get the permissions and it still didn't show on the notification center.

Could anyone tell me how to get the permissions preferably using the inno setup compiler but I will take anything.